# From file to ldif script, attributes separated by comma

Tags: bash, awk, ldif

I have a file like this:

> h3fah055,NG_SYS_UX,NG_SYS_FO,NG_SYS_STG,NG_APP_DWH
>   h3fah058,NG_SYS_UX,NG_SYS_FO,NG_SYS_STG,NG_APP_DWH
>   h3fah065,NG_SYS_UX,NG_SYS_FO,NG_SYS_STG,NG_APP_ERP
>   h3fah066,NG_SYS_UX,NG_SYS_FO,NG_SYS_STG,NG_APP_ERP
>   h3fah082,NG_SYS_UX,NG_SYS_FO,NG_SYS_STG
>   h3fal029,NG_SYS_UX,NG_SYS_FO,NG_SYS_STG
>   h3fal030,NG_SYS_UX,NG_SYS_FO,NG_SYS_STG

I would like to generate an ldif from this file, so for each rows I need to generate:

```
 dn: cn=h3fah055,ou=hosts,dc=example,dc=com
 objectClass: host
 objectClass: ipHost
 objectClass: top
 ipHostNumber: 1.1.1.1
 cn: h3fah055
 Allowednetgroup: NG_SYS_UX
 Allowednetgroup: NG_SYS_FO
 Allowednetgroup: NG_SYS_STG
 Allowednetgroup: NG_APP_DWH
```

How can I read each rows in this file and save, if existing, each netgroup in a variable in order to print in a file my desired output?

I tryed with

```
while read p; do
  echo $p |  awk -F , '{print "dn: cn=" $1 ",ou=hosts,dc=example,dc=com"}'
done <hosts_list.txt
```

But I'm not sure how to add as many `Allowednetgroup` as defined in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk has a variable `NF` which is the number of fields on the line.
So you can loop through them with a `for` statement like this.

```
awk -F',' '{print "dn: cn=" $1 ",ou=hosts,dc=example,dc=com\nobjectClass:host\nobjectclass: ipHost\nobjectClass: top\nipHostNumber 1.1.1.1\ncn:" $1;
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print "Allowednetgroup: " $i  }' hosts_list.txt
```

Notice that awk will read each line itself so you don't need pass one line at a time like your MVCE. Just pass the filename as a second argument.
i.e. `awk '<script>' filename`

The above script will produce output like:

```
dn: cn=h3fah055,ou=hosts,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass:host
objectclass: ipHost
objectClass: top
ipHostNumber 1.1.1.1
cn:h3fah055
Allowednetgroup: NG_SYS_UX
Allowednetgroup: NG_SYS_FO
Allowednetgroup: NG_SYS_STG
Allowednetgroup: NG_APP_DWH
etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the template you can follow

```
awk -F, '{print "cn:",$1; 
          for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print "Allowednetgroup:",$i}'
```

which will handle

```
cn: h3fah055
Allowednetgroup: NG_SYS_UX
Allowednetgroup: NG_SYS_FO
Allowednetgroup: NG_SYS_STG
Allowednetgroup: NG_APP_DWH
```

you can add the top yourself.